# CherryPy combine file and dictionary based configuration

Tags: python, configuration, cherrypy

I'm setting up a CherryPy application and would like to have the majority of my configuration settings in a .conf file like this:

```
[global]
server.socketPort = 8080
server.threadPool = 10
server.environment = "production"
```

However I would also like to setup a few with a dictionary in code like this:

```
conf = {'/': {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 
              'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.join(current_dir, 'templates')}}             

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=conf)
```

Is it possible to combine both configs into one and then pass it into the config quickstart option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`quickstart` is for quick sites. If you're doing anything as complex as having multiple configs, it's time to graduate. Look at the source code for the quickstart function (it's not scary!): you're going to unpack that into your startup script. So instead of `quickstart`, write this:

```
cherrypy.config.update(conffile)
cherrypy.config.update(confdict)

app = cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloWorld(), '/', conffile)
app.merge(confdict)

if hasattr(cherrypy.engine, "signal_handler"):
    cherrypy.engine.signal_handler.subscribe()
if hasattr(cherrypy.engine, "console_control_handler"):
    cherrypy.engine.console_control_handler.subscribe()
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

We've essentially added two lines to the quickstart code. First, we have an extra call to `config.update`; that merges the config dict into the global config. Second, `app.merge(confdict)`; that's for merging multiple configs into each app.

It's perfectly OK to do these in the opposite order if you want the file config to override the dict. It's also OK to stick the dict-based config in `HelloWorld._cp_config` as [described](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/intro/concepts/config.html#cp-config-attaching-config-to-handlers) in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Those are two different configurations. Cherrypy has two configurations: One is the global config and the other is application config. You can use both normally:

```
cherrypy.config.update('my_file.ini')
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=conf)
```

Please note that your example config file is wrong -- instead of `server.socketPort` it should be `server.socket_port` and instead of `server.threadPool` it should be `server.threadpool`. Check [config docs](http://cherrypy.org/wiki/ConfigAPI) for more information.

Comment: Ok, but what I really want to do is specify most config values in the my_file.ini, with a couple of additional that require code.  Is it possible to do both?